# Google Places API for Hospitals

Tags: google-places-api

I am using Google Places API to search nearby **hospitals** from a location. My problem is that I want to get famous and big hospitals but the problem is the API is fetching clinics and even dental clinics too. How I can be more specific?
Query URL : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=24.9044526,67.077706&type=hospital&radius=500&key=[API_KEY]

[image: Image 1 of 2]

[image: Image 2 of 2]

Although they are not famous even the medical facilities provided there are not sufficient for emergency case.

I have also tried increasing the radius but got same response.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a bit old but this worked for me:

```
var request = {
    location: location,
    rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE,
    type: "hospital",
    keyword: "(emergency) AND ((medical centre) OR hospital) AND (24 hours)",
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Text Search, for the query parameter you can say something like "hospital". Filters out the clinics automatically.

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-text#type